# VueJS Cannot find module backgroundImage

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to display background image in a component.

If I understand it well, we must use that:

```
<div class="food-icon"
:title="tooltip"
:style="{backgroundImage: `url(${require(image)})`}">
```

But I get this error

> Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../assets/fast-food.jpg'"

I try it with:

```
<div class="food-icon"
:title="tooltip"
:style="{backgroundImage: `url(${require('../assets/fast-food.jpg')})`}">
```

And that works well, i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet you missed single quotes around `image`

Try:

`url(${require('image')})`

Just remember to whatever you wrap inside `url(' ')` must be quoted to be a valid string.

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't work.
This time he doesn't read the variable :
           Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'image' 

I  try with 
           '' + image 
It makes the same error than  my first post

Comment: yeah because either you didn't provided a valid path or a module to it, try putting the path first, see if that works.

If you are requiring it as a module its a bit more overhead you have to declare it in `
`<script>
import image from '@/path/to/img.png'

export default {
  components: { image }
`